# How to remove similar redefinitions from a file using perl

Tags: perl, shell, perl-module

I have a file which has the following data in it

```
typedef INTEGER Id;
typedef Integer32 Id;
typedef Integer32 Id;
typedef Integer32 Id;
typedef INTEGER Identifier;
typedef Integer32 Index;
typedef Unsigned32 Identifier;
typedef Integer32 Index;
typedef Unsigned32 TunnelId;
typedef Unsigned32 TunnelId;
const Unsigned32 maxValue = 65535;
const Integer32 Index_maxValue = 65535;        
const Unsigned32 maxValue = 4294967295;
const Unsigned32 Index_maxValue = 65535;
```

I need to select the variables in this below order:
If variable has …

- `INTEGER`   and `Integer32`  definitions - `Integer32`  has to be selected
- `Integer32` and `Unsigned32` definitions - `Unsigned32` has to be selected
- `INTEGER`   and `Unsigned32` definitions - `Unsigned32` has to be selected

Output expected :

```
typedef Integer32 Id;
typedef Unsigned32 Identifier;
typedef Integer32 Index;
typedef Unsigned32 TunnelId;
const Unsigned32 maxValue = 65535;
const Unsigned32 Index_maxValue = 65535;
```

I have written the below piece of code …
But its not yielding the above expected result.

```
@file2 = @file // full content of the file in an array
for ($i = 0; $i <= $#file; $i++) {
   $temp = $file[$i];
   $check = $file[$i];
   $check =~ s/^\s+//;

   @fields = split(/ /, $check);

   @grepNames = grep(/$fields[2]/, @file2);

   if($#grepNames >= 1) {

      for ($j = 1; $j <= $#file; $j++) {
         if( $file[$i] =~ /INTEGER/ && $file[$j] =~ /Unsigned32/ ) {
            push(@data, $file[$j]);
         }
         elsif( $file[$i] =~ /INTEGER/ && $file[$j] =~ /Integer32/ ) {
            push(@data, $file[j]);
         }
         elsif( $file[$i] =~ /Unsigned32/ && $file[$j] =~ /Integer32/ ) {
            push(@data, $file[i]);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered to `use strict` and `use warnings` to help you find problems? Does your code even compile? Do you know that Perl's comment character is `#` and not `//`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact that you have accepted **0%** of your questions (It would be very fair to raise that number), here is an analysis of your code, so that you can write better (and working) Perl the next time.

### General comments on writing Perl

#### Discipline vs. Chaos

Always `use strict` and `use warnings`, especially when you are trying to figure out why your script isn't working or when you are new to Perl. Usually, these pragmas alert you about most stupid errors everybody makes once in a while.

Perl doesn't force you to write good code (and TIM TOWDTY), but most of the time you should stick to the `strict` subset of Perl unless you have a *very* good reason.

Using `strict`  implies that you have to declare all your variables with `my`, unless you have a very good reason. I think that declaring variables is a good thing.

#### Perl is not C

Most built-in functions do not need parens to delimit their arguments. I.e. `split(/ /, $check)` and `split / /, $check` are the same thing in most circumstances.

Also, Perl seldomly needs the `for(INIT; COMPARE; INCREMENT)` loop construct, especially when the last part is `$i++`. Instead, you can use the `foreach`-syntax and a *range*:

```
for my $i ($MIN .. $MAX)
```

### Why your code doesn't work

And: what bad idiom can be avoided

I already pointed out that all variables should be declared with `my` and that there is a better loop syntax available.

```
@file2 = @file // full content of the file in an array
```

`//` doesn't introduce a comment. It is the *defined-or* operator. Also, this statement isn't terminated by a `;`. This will confuse Perl, as the following `for` loop is part of the same statement—but this is invalid.

Also, you don't change the contents of either `@file2` or `@file`, therefore making a copy unneccessary.

```
$temp = $file[$i];
```

You never use `$temp`.

```
@grepNames = grep(/$fields[2]/, @file2);
```

You use this `grep` to find out how many lines contain the same variable name. This is superflouus as you loop through *all* elements in `@file` again later on.

```
if($#grepNames >= 1)
```

What you have written is the question: *Is the highest index in `@grepNames` larger than or equal to 1?* whereas you probably meant *Did we have more than one match?*. Id write that as

```
if (@grepNames > 1)
```

However, this is mainly a stylistical comment.

```
if( $file[$i] =~ /INTEGER/ ...
```

Wait what? If `$file[$i]` contains `INTEGER`, so will `$check` or `$temp`. You can save yourself some typing when using a scalar instead of an array subscript.

```
push(@data, $file[$j]);
```

You push something onto `@data` even if you already have a line with the same variable name. Even worse, if `@file` contains *n* elements, then the inner `for` loop iterates over *n - 1* elements, and you push something onto `@data` in most cases, making your algorithm *O(n²)*

```
  i \ j | INTEGER | Int32 | UInt32
--------+---------+-------+-------
INTEGER | -       | j     | j
Int32   | i       | -     | j
UInt32  | i       | i     | -
```

Here is a table that states (according to your rules) which element should make it onto `@data`. You might want to compare this table to your `if`/`elsif`s and figure out if some cases may be missing.

```
push(@data, $file[j]);
```

You forgot the `$` sigil before `j`.

### A better solution

Your algorithm runs in *O(n²)*, or rather *O(n * (2n - 1))*. However, your problem can be solved in *O(n)*.

I viewed the problem as:

> Each line in the input has a identifier and an associated weight.
>
> For the output, that line from the set of all lines with the same identifier is to be selected that has a minimal weight. If two or more lines have the same minimal weight, any of these minimal lines may be selected.
>
> The weight of a line depends on what keyword is the 2nd word in the line:
>
> ```
> Unsigned32 => 1,
> Integer32  => 2,
> INTEGER    => 3,
> ```
>
> If the second word is none of these keywords, an error should be thrown.
>
> The order of the *first* occurrences of each identifier is to be the same in both the input and the output.

In my solution (shown below), I used the 1st and the 3rd word as identifier. If a line was already present in the output, I updated it if the current line had a lower weight.

---

#### Edit: My Solution

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @data;
my %index;

while (<DATA>) {
   $_ =~ s/^\s+//;
   my @fields = split /\s+/, $_, 3;
   @fields = (@fields[0 .. 1], split /(?=\W)/, $fields[2], 2);
   my ($class, $type, $name, $rest) = @fields;
   if (defined $index{$class}{$name}) {
      # we have a predecessor
      my $index = $index{$class}{$name};
      $data[$index][1] = (sort compareTypes $data[$index][1], $type)[0];
   } else {
      push @data, \@fields;
      $index{$class}{$name} = $#data;
   }
}

foreach (@data)  {
   my @fields = @$_;
   print "@fields[0..2]$fields[3]";
}

sub compareTypes {
   my %weight = (
      Unsigned32 => 1,
      Integer32  => 2,
      INTEGER    => 3,
   );
   my $weight_a = $weight{$a} // die "undefined type $a";
   my $weight_b = $weight{$b} // die "undefined type $b";
   return $weight_a <=> $weight_b;
}

__DATA__
typedef INTEGER Id;
typedef Integer32 Id;
typedef Integer32 Id;
typedef Integer32 Id;
typedef INTEGER Identifier;
typedef Integer32 Index;
typedef Unsigned32 Identifier;
typedef Integer32 Index;
typedef Unsigned32 TunnelId;
typedef Unsigned32 TunnelId;
const Unsigned32 maxValue = 65535;
const Integer32 Index_maxValue = 65535;        
const Unsigned32 maxValue = 4294967295;
const Unsigned32 Index_maxValue = 65535;
```

Output:

```
typedef Integer32 Id;
typedef Unsigned32 Identifier;
typedef Integer32 Index;
typedef Unsigned32 TunnelId;
const Unsigned32 maxValue = 65535;
const Unsigned32 Index_maxValue = 65535;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and analysis , i am still a beginner will improve in the future..

Comment: @ShaikMd I added my solution. It might work better than yours, but it contains features you are not yet familiar with: nested hashes and arrays, the `sort` function, the third argument to `split` and array slices.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue , attaching the working code.

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl

open  (DF, "< UNIQ_DEF.txt");
open  (DR, "> DEF_REM.txt");
my @var = <DF>;
my @param =();
my @param2=@var;

for ($i=0; $i<=$#var;$i++)
{
    $temp=$var[$i];
    $check=$var[$i];
    $check=~s/^\s+//;

    @params=split(/ /, $check);

    if (defined $params[2]){

        @Names = grep(/$params[2]/, @param2);

        if($#Names >= 1){
            if ($Names[0] =~ /Unsigned32/ && $Names[1] =~ /Unsigned32/) {
                print DR $Names[0];
            } elsif($Names[0] =~ /INTEGER/ && $Names[1] =~ /Unsigned32/) {              
                print DR $Names[1];
            } elsif($Names[0] =~ /Integer32/ && $Names[1] =~ /Integer32/) {
                print DR $Names[1];
            } elsif($Names[0] =~ /INTEGER/ && $Names[1] =~ /Integer32/) {
                print DR $Names[1];
            } elsif($Names[0] =~ /Integer32/ && $Names[1] =~ /Unsigned32/) {
                print DR $Names[1];
            } elsif($Names[0] =~ /Unsigned32/ && $Names[1] =~ /Integer32/) {
                print DR $Names[0];
            } else {
                print DR $var[$i];
            }
        } else {
            print DR $var[$i];
        }

    } else {
        print DR $var[$i];
    }

}
close(DF);
close(DR);
```